# How to pass interpolated value as an argument into a javascript function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arguments, angularjs-ng-click

I call a function when a button is clicked in html in my angularjs app like below

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="foo(bar, fruits, {{user.email}})">Get it Done</button>
```

`foo` is a function in a controller, `bar` and `fruits` are values from a form and `{{user.email}}` is an email in scope.

I could get `{{user.email}}` displayed on the html page alright, but I get an `undefined` for it in the `foo` function of the controller, when the given `button` is clicked.

```
$scope.foo = function(bar, fruits, email) {
    //email is undefined here
};
```

Could somebody help me understand how could I pass that `{{user.email}}` value to the `foo` function in the controller?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see here http://jsbin.com/mawey/1/edit. You don't have to interpolate `user.email` just:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="foo(bar, fruits, user.email)">
```

Comment: Is it working with `ng-click="foo(bar, fruits, user.email)"`? I tried that first, but it did not work.

Comment: The issue was tht I din't have `user` available inside the `button` element. I thought it was as I had it available at some other part of the page. Thank you :)

Comment: Angular 5 also.